# Как создать временную блокировку?

Tags: php

Допустим надо заблокировать пользователя на 7 дней, вносим в бд дату окончания блокировки, и дату начала... Но вопрос, php выполняет действия при активности на странице, как сделать скрипт который будет работать с блокировками в фоне

Comment: А в чем необходимость фонового выполнения?
Просто при входе пользователя на сайт проверять закончился ли срок бана. Если да, то удалять запись из БД, а если нет, то показывать сообщение о бане.

Comment: Магия за пределами хогвартса запрещена

Comment: Спасибо )))

Comment: ну есть что-то типа `cron` для ваших задач, либо вас спасут `очереди`.